# validation rules on task

Tags: validation-rule

I have a custom activity picklist field `Act_Type__c`. One value of this field is `Gift`.

My requirement is to create a `Task` validation rule that will only allow Activity Type to be `Gift` if the left 3 characters of the `WhatId` are `a12` (`Related To` must be a custom object record).

I'm new to Salesforce, could you please help with this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this validtion formula on Task object:

```
AND(
 ISPICKVAL(Act_Type__c, 'Gift'), 
 NOT(BEGINS(WhatId , 'a12'))
)
```

This basically translates to: If `Act_Type__c` is set to `Gift` **AND** `WhatId` doesn't start with `a12`, throw a validation error.

You can find more information about the above functions by following [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=0).

Answer (score 0):

you can use **BEGINS** function in validation Error Condition Formula.

Here is syntax for the **BEGINS** function:

**BEGINS(text, compare_text)**

Checks if text begins with specified characters and returns TRUE if it does. Otherwise returns FALSE